# Canonical Transformation of Poisson Bracket

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

In Goldstein section 9.4(pg 381) it tells us that for a Hamiltonian that is not explicitly time dependent, transformations of $Q = Q(q,p), P = P(q,p)$ are canonical if $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial P}$$ and $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p} = -\frac{\partial q}{\partial P}.$$

But if we take the following poisson bracket: $$[Q, P]_{q,p} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}\frac{\partial P}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}\frac{\partial P}{\partial q} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial q}{\partial P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial q} = 2.$$
But since this is a fundamental poisson bracket, this should give 1. Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total derivative $\frac{dP}{dP} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial P} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial q}\frac{\partial q}{\partial P}$ equals 1, not the partial derivative $\frac{\partial P}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial P}$.